# MRTK (V2) Need to update Hololens?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to check out the new MRTK (V2) but I had been having troubles making the build, first on Unity which make me download the Windows SDK 18362, now I'm trying to continue the build on Visual Studio 2017 for testing but it brings me this error:

To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.18362.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.17134.80. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.

My Windows 10 OS is 10.0.18632.30 but my HoloLens its on 10.0.17763.380 and its seems it won't update to a higher version even with Windows Insider enabled.

I expect to test the premade demos of MRTK(V2) on my HoloLens 1.
The build on Visual Studio wont pass from the error of incompatible version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this error you need to update your Build Settings so that the Minimum SDK version is at or lower than your HoloLens OS version. I usually use  10.0.10240.0. You still need to make sure that your target SDK version is “latest installed”. Try doing the following steps:

1. Delete your generated UWP project.
2. Open the build settings window in Unity.
3. Make sure that Minimum SDK is is 10.0.10240.0
4. Make sure that Target SDK version is “latest installed”
5. Re-generate the solution and deploy to HoloLens.

Comment: I am running on Windows 10 Insider preview with OS build : 18362.30 Version : 1903 and Also double checked with build setting Minimum SDK is 10.0.10240.0 Target SDK version is “Latest installed”. But still I am facing error at the time of build Error : Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand.cs(418,73): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandJointKind' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Great this works! No more errors before build, now though it seems the debugger gives me another error: 
"DEP6953: Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'Command failed: 0x80070490'. "

Comment: Did exactly this and still get `DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.18362.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.17763.806. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.`

Comment: It sounds like your HoloLens version is 10.0.17763, have you tried updating your HoloLens to a newer version? Go to Settings →  Update → check for updates

Answer (score 1):

Emphasize Bullet 3# in Julia answer.
Minimum SDK **must** be 10.0.10240.0 otherwise you will get a fatal error on the first app run.