# How to solve MapFileParser.exe exited with code -532462766 and cannot open input file GameAssembly.lib?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Unity 2019.2.10f1 IL2cpp + MRTK 2.0 + VS 19 cant make build getting Error MSB3073 MapFileParser.exe exited with code -532462766 and Error LNK1181 cannot open input file \build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.lib

Hi,

I'm not able to make build for HoloLens 1.

I'm using Unity 2019.2.10f1 + MRTK 2.0 + VS19+ Windows 10 v1903 with latest Windows SDK. Getting following errors

**Error MSB3073**
The command ""D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=x86 -configuration=Release -platform=winrt -outputpath="D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\build\bin\Win32\Release\" -cachedirectory="D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\Win32\Release\" -generatedcppdir="D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\Il2CppOutputProject\Source"  --profiler-report --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityaot -verbose --map-file-parser="D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"" exited with code -532462766.    Il2CppOutputProject C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets  44

and

**Error LNK1181**
cannot open input file 'D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.lib'  IModelRendererHCI   D:\Workspace\IMRHL2V1073\IModelRendererHCI\LINK 1

I'm not sure why I am getting MapFileParser.exe"" exited with code -532462766 I've checked if there's space %20 in project paths etc but there's not since my solution is completely loaded in VS 19.

Also I checked my build files and found out that GameAssembly.lib is not generated that why it is not accessible.

Any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Well there is a space after imhrhl and between 2.

Comment: nicely spotted, but removing that space either doesn't solve the error.
I still get same error.

Comment: Look in Visual Studio output window for the real build error.

Comment: This is a rare issue in unity side, could you please try wiped Library and forced the project to do a full re-import and follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626479/11502506 to rebuild your project? If you still have the issue, we recommend that you provide more details about your application, such as the MVCE(stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the steps to reproduce the issue so that you can report it to unity as a bug.